# When input checkbox is checked, load a value on the nearby input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I can't manage to code at all, by gathering code from here and there, I could make a daily Todo with upcount timer.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTFLZ67IZSJM

I'll write on my daily plan in class="planbox" , after solve one by one, I hope to the upcount value(var= hour : minuets : seconds ) will be loaded on .planbox as most front side of the text without maintain the original text that I wrote.

```
<div id="checklist">
<input type="checkbox" class="c1 checkout"></input><input type="text" class="c1 planbox"></input><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="c2 checkout"></input><input type="text" class="c2 planbox"></input><br>
</div>
```

`$(':checkbox').change(function() $(this).next().val('New value');})`

ut I couldn't find a hint to put the upcount timestamp when the left side of the checkbox is checked.
When I finish the 'a thing to do' then select the checkbox, I want the current upcount value loaded on to the front of the text inbox.

Comment: sorry that I'm being a newb, I assume I couldn't ask this on here.

Comment: If someone is middle in answering on it. then I'm feel so sorry, I'm gonna remove this post soon.

Comment: Put the relevant part of the code into the question itself. It really appears you are trying to accomplish something by looking at that link and may get help by showing the code here. Demos are great, but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: Thanks to letting me charlietfl ! , I'll edit this post again !

Comment: Ok so now we need to improve the description of exactly what each checkbox should do. You can try something simple like `$(':checkbox').change(function() {$(this).next().val('New value');})`

Comment: charlietfl Sorry I don't understand what's meaning the like of the example that you wrote. maybe is that the example code to to make other's know how do I want to put a function?

Comment: yeah I pasted the example on the post thanks charliefl ! I hope it would be more better if I could do make my own version of example, and thanks for proofread my sham English nOnAmE :) !

Comment: Ok and I'm confused what each checkbox should do. My code will simply show "new value" in `<input>` beside whichever checkbox you change for now

Comment: So now if you can improve the question ...  *'first checkbox should do..."* etc. Learning how to ask questions here will get you help much faster...when the problem is very clear

Comment: Aha, if the code means put the value 'New value' text for the input area then, I might try my own to load the clock value now on!

Comment: okay then before try my own I'll give shape thanks !

Comment: OK. Then you might start running into problems matching various parts of clock value to checkbox...make a well detailed question for that if you do

Comment: thanks for guiding me how to make a question in detail charlietfl :D yeah I feel like I'm get how to give more detail on the question and same time I'm trying to solve the problem myself!

Comment: Is still a bit confusing looking at your link seeing many checkboxes then reading question. So try to be as specific as you can explaining things. Good for you though....seems you are learning bit by bit. How to ask questions is a learning curve also

Comment: Yeah I trimmed code to make easy to understand. It's fun but quite changeable for me than I expected. but feel like it's getting close to solve though !

Comment: Great. So if you run into more problems...suggest you start a brand new question here for it. Ones with this many comments are hard for others to read since a lot of it is more about how to use this site and how to ask. I think you now have a better grasp on how to ask here also. And if you think it's all confusing.... was same for everyone that had to learn

Comment: chelietfl thanks for sincere help on me, I finally solve the think and by this experience I got a clue to how to deal with javascript..! without your first comment, I've probably just gave up to solve, It's already mid night here but It was such a joyful challenge as much I forgot sleepy during a hour. thanks for letting me take first step on stack overflow! yeahah !

Comment: cool...can tell you are now a coding addict!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen the ':checkbox' selector or changed used to detecting checkbox events/value much before maybe it can work, the example below should work for you.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
  .click(function() {
     // this.checked can be tested to if you need to do different things depending on if it checked or not  
     $(this).next('input[type=text]').val( $(this).val() ); 
  })
```

and the input tag is self closing

```
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: thanks for leave an answer on my question. I pasted your code most bottom side of my previous code, however it returns "[object Object]" on the text field. and same time it removes the original text on the box. I wanted to put an text most front side of the text, would it be possible without remove original text?

Comment: you've put 'hh' in the val() instead of putting value="something" into the checkbox input.

Comment: and if you jusst what to add to the value already in the text input use something like $(this).next('input[type=text]').val( $(this).next('input[type=text]').val() 
 + $(this).val() );

Comment: oh ! a text "on" is keep wrote on at the end of text box ! feel like it's getting closer! thanks for your help digital-pollution.

Comment: I want to give some code like 
$('input[type=checkbox]')
  .click(function() {
     $(this).next('input[type=text]').val($(this).val(hour +":"+ minues +":"+ second) + $(this).next('input[type=text]').val())
  })
which the var of hour, minues and second are already given by upper script, but  it failed to load and change nothing though. sorry for asking you probably such a basic stuffs ;0

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTFMHA5ISBAD link is my progress so far